# Cannot read property parentNode of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

i'm using react-ga from track my react app using google analytics. I'm fetching the tracking id through an API call and is returned after approximately 4 seconds. My function is this:

```
const withTracker = (WrappedComponent, options = {}) => {
  const trackPage = (page) => {
    ReactGA.set({
      page,
      options
    });
    ReactGA.pageview(page);
  };

  class HOC extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      ReactGA.initialize(this.props.partnerTrackingCode);
      const page = this.props.location.pathname;
      trackPage(page);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      console.log(nextProps);
      const currentPage = this.props.location.pathname;
      const nextPage = nextProps.location.pathname;

      if (currentPage !== nextPage) {
        trackPage(nextPage);
      }
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  return HOC;
};

export default withTracker;
```

The problem is that the initiliaze function must be called first and is being called with undefined because at first the trackid is undefined(remember that is fetched asynchronously). I used this edit:

```
const withTracker = (WrappedComponent, options = {}) => {
      const trackPage = (page) => {
        ReactGA.set({
          page,
          options
        });
        ReactGA.pageview(page);
      };

      class HOC extends Component {
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
          if(nextProps.trackId) {
            ReactGA.initiliaze(nextProps.trackId);
            const currentPage = this.props.location.pathname;
            const nextPage = nextProps.location.pathname;
            trackPage(nextPage);
         }
        }

        render() {
          return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
        }
      }

      return HOC;
    };
```

i'm using react-ga from track my react app using google analytics. I'm fetching the tracking id through an API call and is returned after approximately 4 seconds. My function is this:

```
const withTracker = (WrappedComponent, options = {}) => {
  const trackPage = (page) => {
    ReactGA.set({
      page,
      options
    });
    ReactGA.pageview(page);
  };

  class HOC extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      ReactGA.initialize(this.props.partnerTrackingCode);
      const page = this.props.location.pathname;
      trackPage(page);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      console.log(nextProps);
      const currentPage = this.props.location.pathname;
      const nextPage = nextProps.location.pathname;

      if (currentPage !== nextPage) {
        trackPage(nextPage);
      }
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  return HOC;
};

export default withTracker;
```

The problem is that the initiliaze function must be called first and is being called with undefined because at first the trackid is undefined(remember that is fetched asynchronously). I used this edit:

```
const withTracker = (WrappedComponent, options = {}) => {
      const trackPage = (page) => {
        ReactGA.set({
          page,
          options
        });
        ReactGA.pageview(page);
      };

      class HOC extends Component {
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
          if(nextProps.trackId) {
            ReactGA.initiliaze(nextProps.trackId);
            const currentPage = this.props.location.pathname;
            const nextPage = nextProps.location.pathname;
            trackPage(nextPage);
         }
        }

        render() {
          return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
        }
      }

      return HOC;
    };
```

but i'm getting an error that **cannot read property parentNode of undefined** Do you have an ideas what to do?

Comment: any clue as to which part of your code is responsible - because `parentNode` isn't used in your code at all - perhaps the stack trace can pinpoint the problem

Comment: Yes it's this:  ReactGA.initiliaze(nextProps.trackId); even though nextProps.trackId is actually returning a value this error is showing and i dont know why

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: no unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the username like this `GoogleAnalytics.set({ username });` before making a call to  `GoogleAnalytics.initialize`? If not try to do that and see if it makes a difference. I had the same issue just now and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `initialize` attempts to inserting an element in the first script element.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
```

If seen this throw `Cannot read property parentNode of undefined` in test environments. It might also do this if you are running JS in node?